# how to save editText color,size,Typeface?

Tags: android, android-edittext

i have an editText and I have a button that changes the color ,size and Typeface so when saving the file as pdf or txt file how can i get the this 3 things with the text i'm getting only the text with normal black style this is my code.

```
 size.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            txtSpeechInput.setTextSize(25);
            txtSpeechInput.setTextColor(Color.rgb(150,0,0));
            txtSpeechInput.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

the save code:

```
final File externalStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyVoiceText");

            boolean success = true;
            if (!externalStorageDir.exists()) {
                success = externalStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            if (success) {
                final Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_save);
                dialog2.show();
                editsave = (EditText) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.edit_save);
                pdf = (Button) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.pdf_save);
                pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        pdf.setEnabled(false);
                        txt.setEnabled(true);

                    }
                });

                txt = (Button) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.txt_save);
                txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        txt.setEnabled(false);
                        pdf.setEnabled(true);

                    }
                });
                dia_save = (Button) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.dia_save);
                dia_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String savename = editsave.getText().toString();

                        if(!txt.isEnabled()) {
                            File myFile = new File(externalStorageDir + "/" + savename + ".txt");

                              File myFile = new File(externalStorageDir + "/" + savename + ".txt");

                            try {
                                StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer();

                                string.append(txtSpeechInput.getText().toString());
                                Properties properties = new Properties();
                                // set the properties value
                                properties.put("text",string.append(txtSpeechInput.getText().toString()));                                    properties.put("textstyle","bold");
                                properties.put("typeface",txtstyle);
                                properties.put("etxtColor",txtcolor);

                                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                                myOutWriter.append(string);

                                myOutWriter.close();
                                fOut.flush();
                                fOut.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }


                            try {
                                myFile.createNewFile();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            dialog2.dismiss();
                        }else if(!pdf.isEnabled()){
                            try
                           {

                                String savename2 = editsave.getText().toString();

                                String takeit = txtSpeechInput.getText().toString();

                                   Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                                Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
                                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyVoiceText/" +savename2+".pdf"));
                                document.open();
                                writer.getDirectContent();
                                p.add(new Phrase(takeit));



                                document.add(p);

                                document.close();
                                Log.d("OK", "done");

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            //LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
                        }
```

reload the text file

```
 File sdcard = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/MyVoiceText/");
                        //Get the text file
                     File file = new File(sdcard, String.valueOf(selected));
                        InputStream input = null;
                        try {
                            input = new FileInputStream(file);
                            Properties prop = new Properties();
                            // load a properties file
                            prop.load(input);
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        //Read text from file
                        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                        try {
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                            String line;

                            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                text.append(line);

                            }
                            br.close();
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            //You'll need to add proper error handling here
                        }
```

Comment: Changing the size, font and color of textView is different thing and changing the size, font and color of text in pdf.

Comment: okay that is my question how can i save the file with custom color,...,..

Comment: for this you may keep all portieres of you text like color , text , text style , typeface into one class like TextPojo and keep it in Server or local database or application Context .

Comment: so is there a code to have this 3 things like (getText.toString) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your code, it seems like you are using iTextPDF library to generate the PDF.
Use Font class of iTextPDF to create a new font and use it like below:

```
private static Font HelveticaBlue = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6,
            Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLUE);
new Paragraph("Blue ColorText"), HelveticaBlue);
```

Comment: I don't want to edit anything when saving the file I want to getColor or ...,.....  of the Edit text then save it like how it showing it on my editTexxt

Comment: Are you using iTextPDF to generate the PDF?

Comment: maybe u didn't get my question ur code works fine with changing everything but i want to get all of this from the editText to pdf

Comment: You will need to save the values of font_family, font_size and font_color to some variables in size.setOnClickListener() function where you are changing color of textView. And use these values while writing text to the PDF Document.

Comment: thanks  i make it work with some editing on the code but this is the main code for the pdf

Answer (score 0):

We can add `Properties` to File that contains entries in key and value format.

And we can write our own `Properties` in `File` also retrieve.

like below code:

Write Properties to File:

```
 private void addPropertiesToFile(String mytext){
        try {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/CHETAN");
            if (!myDir.exists ())
            myDir.mkdirs();
            String fname = "mytext.txt";
            File myFile = new File (myDir, fname);
            if (!myFile.exists ())
            myFile.createNewFile();
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            // set the properties value
            properties.put("text","dsf");
            properties.put("textstyle","bold");
            properties.put("typeface","arial");
            properties.put("etxtColor","green");

            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.write(mytext);
            // save properties to project root folder
            properties.store(myOutWriter,null);
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Retrieve Properties from File:

```
private void retrievePropertiesFromFile(){
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/CHETAN");
        String fname = "mytext.txt";
        File myFile = new File (myDir, fname);

        InputStream input = null;
        try {
        input = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);
        // get the property value and print it out
         Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),prop.getProperty("text"));
         Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),prop.getProperty("textstyle"));
         Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),prop.getProperty("typeface"));
         Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),prop.getProperty("typeface"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: when i close the application an reopen it then open my file the font back to normal black of course i added my custom int for color , typeface and size

Comment: when i added                                     properties.store(myOutWriter,null);
 i cant get the text

Comment: Actually Properties are extra information of your file .So its not applied on your text its just information you get this information and apply again to your text  manually

Comment: check it but i guess the code not working because i'm giving color to the all editText so it change the color to all new and loaded text so when i press load button for the file that had blue text comes as green if i was selected green in the app

Comment: see my code i have used    myOutWriter.write(mytext); to write my text into file not used append .

Comment: Also when you want to get your propertice you are using BufferedReader object and in my code i have used     input = new ileInputStream(myFile);
Properties prop = new Properties();// load a properties file
prop.load(input);

Comment: i cant use the load properties in bufferedReader because InputStream not working for me

Comment: I know for reading text you need bufferedReader but for propertice you need to pass  inputstream object into load() method .

Comment: if think properties are applied directly , I dont think it working but you should get all values from properties and then applied on TextView then it could be a solution of your problem.

Comment: aha so it is not possible to give values after the text like(int) my code